# WPF overlay example, binding not work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, overlay

I tried today this example => http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2011/05/31/wpf-simple-busy-overlay.aspx for simple overlay in my window to show the user im proceeding his action.
But I have a little problem. In my function to proceed the action I switch the `IsBusy` property at the beginning to `true` and at the end to `false`. But the gui does not update and i don't see the overlay. I tried an extra button to switch the overlay and it works.

Do someone know why I have this problem? I think it has something to do with the priority of binding operations, but I don't know it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your own code...

Is it possible that the operation to switch the `IsBusy` property is happening on the UI/Main thread? So, the UI actually doesn't get a chance to 'refresh' itself between you setting the property true and then back to false?

If you **only** set `IsBusy = true` but not back to false, is the overlay shown? If yes, then this is probably what's happening; you need to invoke the method on a different thread so the UI can update.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IsBusy` property needs to be either a dependency property or implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to make the UI recognize its changes. Otherwise the UI will not know that you set the property and as such won’t show the overlay.

For unknown reasons this is not done in the [example source](https://bitbucket.org/psteele/samplebusyoverlay/src/default/SampleBusyOverlay/BusyViewModel.cs) of your example so it shouldn’t work there either. In short, you basically want to raise the `PropertyChanged` event after setting the `IsBusy` property.